# MKDirections calculate directions when app is in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I want to calculate directions to a destination when my app is in the background every time it receives a location update.

However, the `[MKDirections calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler]` is an asynchronous call, and my question is therefore: will my app be terminated if this takes more than 5 seconds to complete after my app has received a location update? What would be your recommendations to make sure this request has enough time to finish?

Comment: Huh? Asynchronous = background

Comment: @LyndseyScott Yes, but the way I understand this is that when requesting extra time, all the stuff you do needs to be synchronous. That's at least what I've gotten out of all the tutorials I've read. 
**EDIT:** I understand your confusion. What I meant is that my app is actually backgrounded, terminated, etc.

Comment: Oh gotcha. You can request up to a few minutes to complete the task: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Comment: @LyndseyScott but doesn't all the tasks have to be synchronous when doing so?

Comment: No, I've used this method with asynchronous tasks. I'm looking through old code right now for the specifics...

Comment: @LyndseyScott oh ok, then I've just misunderstood something somewhere. Thanks! Would you mind posting this as an answer, so I can close the thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to request extra time for your app to run in the background to complete its tasks (asynchronous or not), you can use [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).

For example:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    // If the application is in the background...
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] != UIApplicationStateActive) {

        // Create the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
        // which will execute once your task is complete
        bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
            // stopped or ending the task outright.
            [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];

        // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [dict setObject:application forKey:@"application"];

            // Start a timer to keep the program alive for 180 seconds max
            // (less if that's all that's necessary)
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:180 target:self selector:@selector(delayMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        });

    }

    // ... the rest of your didUpdateToLocation: code ...

}

- (void)delayMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {

    // End the background task you created with beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
    [[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"application"] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```